# Call to undefined method Imagick::roundCorners() on MacOSX

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, imagick, php-7

I use homebrew to upgrade php and php-imagick from php55 to php70/71.

```
$image = new Imagick( $filename );
$image->roundCorners(10,10)
```

roundCorners method will cause exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Imagick::roundCorners()
```

This method works well with php55-imagick on same MacOSX machine. And I try run the same script on ubuntu with php70-imagick, that works well.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: What version of Imagick do you have installed with php7?

Comment: convert Version: ImageMagick 7.0.4-7 Q16 x86_64 2017-02-04 http://www.imagemagick.org.

Comment: Er, it looks like the maintainer of the Imagick extension might have screwed up and accidentally excluded that method from being compiled when ImageMagick 7 is used, due to the changes of Matte to Alpha in ImageMagick....It should be pretty easy to make an equivalent function in userland.